# How to convert dual channel audio to mono with ability to control each channel volume?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I'm trying to listen 2 channel audio in both headphones(same audio in left and right headphone).

Current situaltion:

Slider is centered - works perfectly well (both channels in both headphones).

Slider is on the right - works perfectly well (right channel in both headphones).

Slider is on the left - doesn't work (left channel only in left headphone).

```
const splitter = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createChannelSplitter(2);
const merger = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createChannelMerger(2);
const leftGain = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createGain();
const rightGain = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createGain();
const panner = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createPanner();

splitter.connect(leftGain, 0);
splitter.connect(rightGain, 1);

leftGain.connect(merger, 0, 0);
rightGain.connect(merger, 0, 1);

merger.connect(panner);

let slider = document.querySelector('#Slider');
$(slider ).change(function () {
    rightGain.gain.value = Number(slider.value);
    leftGain.gain.value = 1- (Number(slider.value));
})

wavesurfer.backend.setFilters([splitter, leftGain, rightGain, merger]);
```

When slider is on the left I want to hear only left channel in both headphones.
Can someone help me?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oPYQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling [setFilters()](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/blob/45144cf7d4a0424aff3878d918bda9a44197b6e4/src/webaudio.js#L218) waversurfer.js will connect all provided nodes in a simple chain. In your case that means it will create additional connections like this:

```
splitter.connect(leftGain);
leftGain.connect(rightGain);
rightGain.connect(merger);
```

This is probably not what you want. But it is possible to make use of that behavior. I modified your example a bit.

```
const input = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createGain();
const splitter = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createChannelSplitter(2);
const merger = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createChannelMerger(2);
const leftGain = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createGain();
const rightGain = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createGain();

// This will make sure that a mono signal gets upmixed to stereo.
// If you always have stereo sound you can remove it.
input.channelCountMode = 'explicit';

// It is only necessary to connect the right channel
// because this is the one which needs optional parameters.
splitter.connect(rightGain, 1);
rightGain.connect(merger);
rightGain.connect(merger, 0, 1);

// Only the one connection which needs an optional parameter
// needs to be done for the left channel
leftGain.connect(merger, 0, 1);

// wavesufer.js will connect everything else.
wavesurfer.backend.setFilters([ input, splitter, leftGain, merger ]);
```

I also added another GainNode as the first node to make sure the signal is upmixed to stereo in case it is mono. And I removed the PannerNode as it wasn't used in your example.

Comment: Works great, but this is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Now it is just stereo with channel control (when im sliding sound goes from left to right headphone).
I need to hear both channel in left and right headphone (like mono), but when sliding, for example to right, sound should still be in both headphones, but right channel should be audible while left should be muted.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow misunderstood the last sentence of your question. I updated the code block above.